# PrintArea for Excel spreadsheet not working

Tags: html, salesforce, export, spreadsheet

I have one export to Excel button in VF page and am trying to set basic print settings for that. In my Excel sheet width is fixed (always from A to P columns).

```
<WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <PageSetup>
    <Layout x:Orientation="Landscape"/>
    <Header x:Margin="0.76"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.76"/> 
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="1.91" x:Left="0.64" x:Right="0.64" x:Top="1.91" x:Header="0.76" x:Footer="0.76" />  
    <PrintArea>A:J</PrintArea>
  </PageSetup>
  <FitToPage/>
  <Print>
    <FitHeight>100</FitHeight>
    <FitWidth>1</FitWidth>
    <ValidPrinterInfo/>
    <HorizontalResolution>600</HorizontalResolution>
    <VerticalResolution>600</VerticalResolution>
  </Print>
  <Selected/>
  <Panes>
    <Pane>
      <Number>3</Number>
      <ActiveRow>6</ActiveRow>
      <ActiveCol>8</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
  </Panes>
  <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
  <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
</WorksheetOptions>
```

I want to set print setting for print area A to P only but how do I do this?